# DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'ddlCustomerName'. Remove one definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to track page name from entire solution when we have got below error message

> "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'ddlCustomerName'. 
>   Remove one definition."

i have checked in entire solution but i did not get both DataSource and DataSourceID .
still i am not able to figure out what is actual problem.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + F will give you the option to search for text in entire solution.  Search for `ddlCustomerName.DataSource`

Comment: pls let me know why i am getting this message

Answer (score 0):

Your `DropDownList`: `ddlCustomerName` has both it's `DataSource` and `DataSourceID` properties set.  Only one can be set.

Check your entire solution for your control.
Then ensure only one of those properties are set, both in the xHTML and in your .cs file.

Comment: Post your xhtml and your .cs code where this control exists, please.